# Where can I find MSCVR80.DLL v8.0.50727.3053?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, dll

I've got a bug from one of our customers and believe that the problem lies with **MSVCR80.DLL v8.0.50727.3053** - a version which I cannot find for download anywhere, however a [google search](http://google.com/search?q=MSVCR80.DLL+8.0.50727.3053) turns up plenty of other crash reports.

Latest version on my system (and others here) is 8.0.50727.1433 and the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=200b2fd9-ae1a-4a14-984d-389c36f85647&displaylang=en) is only version 8.0.5027.762 (currently same as the merge module we use)

Is there an "official" link to get this update? Is it bundled with any other Microsoft products?

**EDIT:** please don't email it to me, I'm looking for the SxS install.

**EDIT2:** damn, that wasn't the problem after all :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A thread on the MSDN forums [pointed out the answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsworkflowfoundation/thread/5d57e3b1-80c0-43c2-8eab-0b7c4fe168e2/): msvcr80.dll version 8.0.50727.3053 is included in [.NET Framework 3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=ab99342f-5d1a-413d-8319-81da479ab0d7&displaylang=en)

Comment: This is correct.  I just ran across it today (fortunately before anything was built and shipped to a customer).

Comment: Excellent, I thought I'd installed 3.5 SP1 but I guess not!

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be able to answer this question using Microsoft's DLL Help Database http://support.microsoft.com/dllhelp/

Unfortunately, when I try it, I only get two answers for msvcr80.dll whereas there ought to be dozens of different versions: and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use merge modules from "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Merge Modules".